# Why does the image at the top of http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage point to the 1.0 api?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackapps

The image at the top of http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/ that says "Stack Exchange" points to http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks completed to me, so marking it as such.